# Killing containers using docker stats results

Tags: docker, awk, containers, cpu

Trying to figure out how to kill a container that has its cpu usage over 100% using the docker stats results.  I have created the below script that exports the stats to a file then looks at the results and looks for container id with cpu over 100% and kills it the problem is it looks like it is killing containers that are at 40%.  The results return in this format 00.00% which I think might be the problem but not sure how the awk views the number when comparing to the % in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
docker stats --no-stream > /tmp/cpu.log

sed -i 's/CONTAINER//g' /tmp/cpu.log

KILLCPU=$(awk '$2 >= 11000 {print$1}' /tmp/cpu.log)

docker stop $KILLCPU
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `+0` to the field to get `awk` to properly recognize the percentage.

```
KILLCPU=$(awk '$2+0 >= 110 {print$1}' /tmp/cpu.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a containers uses > 100% CPU it is running on more than one CPU.  Killing them because they reach a certain percentage is not the correct approach.

I suggest you use the `--cpu-shares` option to docker run:

See:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-share-constraint

> CPU share constraint By default, all containers get the same
>   proportion of CPU cycles. This proportion can be modified by changing
>   the container’s CPU share weighting relative to the weighting of all
>   other running containers.
>
> To modify the proportion from the default of 1024, use the -c or
>   --cpu-shares flag to set the weighting to 2 or higher. If 0 is set, the system will ignore the value and use the default of 1024.
>
> The proportion will only apply when CPU-intensive processes are
>   running. When tasks in one container are idle, other containers can
>   use the left-over CPU time. The actual amount of CPU time will vary
>   depending on the number of containers running on the system.
>
> For example, consider three containers, one has a cpu-share of 1024
>   and two others have a cpu-share setting of 512. When processes in all
>   three containers attempt to use 100% of CPU, the first container would
>   receive 50% of the total CPU time. If you add a fourth container with
>   a cpu-share of 1024, the first container only gets 33% of the CPU. The
>   remaining containers receive 16.5%, 16.5% and 33% of the CPU.
>
> On a multi-core system, the shares of CPU time are distributed over
>   all CPU cores. Even if a container is limited to less than 100% of CPU
>   time, it can use 100% of each individual CPU core.
>
> For example, consider a system with more than three cores. If you
>   start one container {C0} with -c=512 running one process, and another
>   container {C1} with -c=1024 running two processes, this can result in
>   the following division of CPU shares:

```
PID    container    CPU CPU share
100    {C0}     0   100% of CPU0
101    {C1}     1   100% of CPU1
102    {C1}     2   100% of CPU2
```